# What makes searchDisplayController show the scopeBar?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I know there is a property `searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsScopeBar`, but in my finding even if we set `showsScopeBar` to NO, but set its `searchDisplayController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles` property to some array, the scope bar appears with specified titles. Setting `showsScopeBar` to YES, and setting `scopeButtonTitles` to `nil`, does not show the `scopeBar`.

So, I think `showsScopeBar` property is really not being useful, but showing or hiding of `scopeBar` is actually depending on whether we set an array to `scopeButtonTitles` property.

Can this be possible? Or Am I missing something else.

Comment: Regarding scopeButtonTitles (from the `UISearchBar.h` header): `@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray   *scopeButtonTitles        NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0); // array of NSStrings. no scope bar
 shown unless 2 or more items`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your UISearchBar has a space to extend into when the scope bar appears. I made a mistake by having the UISearchBar inside a fixed frame of 320x44px and when the scope bar was ON, it simply didn't have space to be visible (320x88px). Also the UISearchBar was in table's header view that must be told to refresh as well.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES]; 
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to be accurate, showsScopeBar and scopeButtonTitles 
are properties of UISearchBar class.

It goes like this:

- If scopeButtonTitles has value(s) and showsScopeBar == NO
  The scope buttons will appear only once the user has clicked on the Search text-box.
- If scopeButtonTitles has value(s) and showsScopeBar == YES
  The scope buttons are displayed even before the user clicked on the Search text-box.
  (quite ugly, dont go this way)
- If scopeButtonTitles is nil
  The scope buttons will not be displayed regardless of showsScopeBar value or user interaction.

You can use Interface Builder to play with it:
Click on "Search Bar" controller and go to "Attributes inspector" tab.